# Augmented Reality + Realtime Image Recognition on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, augmented-reality, image-recognition

I am not sure if this question has been asked before or not, but I want to know what frameworks do I need to explore in order to do augmented reality with image recognition for iOS.

Basically to build something like this, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbplSdh0lGU

Answer (score 1):

I am using Wikitude's SDK which enables me to use it in PhoneGap as well. Wikitude uses Vuforia's SDK for Image Recognition. Compare Wikitude and Vuforia for their features!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good SDK which I know for Augmented Reality. You will find tutorials and demos there.
Note: Adding vuforia SDK with your app is difficult so you can go with metaio SDK but modification(changing target image is easy in Vuforia)

http://www.metaio.com/sdk/
https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps